# COGNOS error: 'sqlOpenResult' status = '-237'

Tags: reporting, cognos

I am trying to devise a crosstab report for COGNOS.  I am joining a main query to a dimension query so that all crosstabs will nicely line up with one another.  When I ask to view the tabular data for either the main query or the dimension query, it displays fine.  The main query as about 10,000 records and the dimension query 70 records.

However, when I run the report as normal, or view the tabular data for the crosstab query, I get an RQP-DEF-0177 error.

```
An error occurred while performing operation 'sqlOpenResult' status='-237'.
```

and the error details begin:

```
UDA-SOR-0005 Unable to write the file.RSV-SRV-0042 Trace back:RSReportService.cpp(724)
```

followed by a bunch of QFException clauses.

How could I fix this problem?

Comment: Sounds like you're running out of temp space. Make sure you're joining the two queries correctly.

Comment: I am running COGNOS on Internet Explorer in a Windows environment.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear. That error makes me think that the server where the report is executing is running out of temp space.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to insufficient disk space for Temporary files.  Check IBM Cognos configuration -> Environment -> Temporary files location.
When a report is running a UDA file is created inside the temp folder and disk may not have enough space to for UDA file to expand. By increasing the disk space where the temp folder is located will resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is generic error, most of the times cognos throws this error, if you want go in details go to /logs/cogserver.log , you will find more details there.