# Cognos scheduled report e-mail with current date

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-11

I want to schedule the mailing of a Cognos report, always using the current date. So, for example: today, I want to e-mail the report with data up until the 28th, but tomorrow it should contain data up until the 29th.
How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you're expecting code, you didn't provide enough information, but let me try...

Assuming the "date" data against which you want to filter is in a query item named [Date] which is in a query subject named [Time] which is in a namespace named [namespace], create a filter like this:

```
[namespace].[Time].[Date] = current_date
```

Comment: this gives me the following error: 'sqlOpenResult' status='-237'.
Do you know what causes this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39106308/cognos-error-sqlopenresult-status-237  This seems unrelated to your question or my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want up to the current date which includes the days leading up to it you can use what dougp posted slightly modified.

[namespace].[Time].[Date] <= current_date

to ensure the where clause is pushed down to the database, I personally like to use a macro for current_date.  So the expression becomes

[namespace].[Time].[Date] <= # timestampMask ( $current_timestamp , 'yyyy-mm-dd' ) #